# What are the names of the Portal 2 co-op robots?

Tags: portal-2

Does anyone know the names of the Portal 2 coop robots or even if they have names?

[image]

Comment: There are coop robots? Cool!

Comment: Apparently [they may not have any name at all.](http://blogs.wsj.com/speakeasy/2010/09/04/portal-2-a-look-at-the-hotly-anticipated-videogame/)

Comment: I edited it slightly to try to avoid closure (this is an OK question IMO)

Comment: first question about Portal 2, yeah :D

Comment: If people wanna see them in action, here is the first official trailer with these two robots: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A88YiZdXugA

Comment: At the end, they will make a cake for you!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They have official names now: **Atlas**, The stout blue one, and **P-Body**, the slim yellow one.

References:

- http://www.wired.com/video/portal-2-atlas-and-pbody-prepare-for-testing/713558795001
- http://www.examiner.com/pc-game-in-national/portal-2-video-shows-atlas-and-p-body

Comment: Just to add a little clarity: The stocky, shorter, blue-eyed robot's name is **Atlas**, and the slender, lithe, orange-eyed robot's name is **P-Body**.

Answer (score 2):

The informal nicknames around the blogosphere right now is Red and Blue. Here is a [link](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/09/03/portal-2-multiplayer-screens-from-pax-will-win-your-heart/) showing the red/blue names in action

Answer (score -2):

The shorter one's name is Atlas (whom GLaDOS calls Blue) and the taller one is P-body (GLaDOS calls him Orange).

Answer (score -2):

The orange one is P-body, and the short blue one is Atlas.

Comment: Is there a credible source for this answer?